# Java regular expression Anything{100}SomethingAnything{100}, need left-right chars to be saved

Tags: java, regex

How to match - anything{100Chars}+MyString+anything{100Chars}? And I need to get left and right string saved.
This thing doesn't work(Does not find the pattern string is text, leftContext as RightContext are null):

```
String text="*SomeText*";
String word = hello; 
int nLeft=100; 
int nRight=100;

String wordDelRegEx = "[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]+?";
String leftRegEx = "[\\w]{" + nLeft + "}";     
String rightRegEx = "[\\w]{" + nRight + "}";

String contextRe = leftRegEx + wordDelRegEx + word + wordDelRegEx + rightRegEx;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(contextRe);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Text);
while (matcher.find()) {
        leftContext = matcher.group(1);
        rightContext = matcher.group(2);
    }

    System.out.println("Left: " + leftContext);
    System.out.print("Right: " + rightContext);
```

For example I have text:

> If you haven't found it yet, keep looking. Don't settle. As with all matters of the heart, you'll know when you find it. And, like any great relationship, it just gets better and better as the years roll on

```
word="heart", nLeft=5, nRight=5
```

The output I want to see:

```
Left:   " the "
Right:  ", you"
```

Comment: Put capturing parentheses around the stuff you want captured.

Comment: Consider posting example which will demonstrate what you want to achieve. To simplify things don't search for 100 characters but something shorter, like 3-5 characters. Also "*This thing doesn't work*" doesn't actually describe your problem, which means that others with similar problem will not be able to find your question and answers to it.

Comment: can you post a sample data and you desired output?

Comment: It didn't help. I edited my question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Add capturing parentheses:

```
String leftRegEx = "(\\w{" + nLeft + "})";     
String rightRegEx = "(\\w{" + nRight + "})";
```

Comment: My matcher still didn't find it. I edited my question, hope it helps.

Comment: Missed the fact that the `[` and `]` were there. They are unnecessary.